# Direction of $\hat\theta $ and $\hat r$ in pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

When trying to find $\alpha (t)$ , I have $F_{mg}=mg(\cos{\alpha}\hat r  +  \sin{\alpha}\hat\theta)$. Using the assumption the rope remains the same length, I get the ODE (from the equation of acceleration in polar coordinates):

$mg\sin{\alpha}=mL \ddot\alpha$ which gives $\alpha (t)=c_1e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{g/L}}}+c_2e^{\frac{-t}{\sqrt{g/L}}}$ (for small angle, $\sin{\alpha}\approx\alpha$). However, if I change the direction of $\hat\theta$ to the opposite, it becomes $-mg\sin{\alpha}=mL \ddot\alpha$, and we get the known solution, $\alpha (t)=c_1\sin(t\sqrt{g/L}) + c_2\cos(t\sqrt{g/L})$. Also $\sqrt{g/L}=\omega$

My question is why changing the axis gives wrong solution? and how to know which direction to choose on further questions?

Comment: Hello, can you please clarify which angle is for you $\theta$? It may seem trivial ($\alpha = \theta$) but note that your two angle $\alpha$ are not the same since they are on opposite sides of the vertical. It creates a bit of confusion about which you are referring to, also it "converts" a sine into a cosine if you are not careful.

Comment: $\alpha$ is $\theta$, but which $\alpha$?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the confusion, edited now

Comment: The general principle is that the outcome is a physical thing and cannot possibly depend on the choice of coordinates. Therefore, it doesn't matter which coordinate system you choose, although in many cases one choice is much more natural than others. If you are getting different results, it means that you are making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: As such, I'm voting to close this as opinion-based (your first question is a "find my mistake for me" question while your second question is opinion-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your mistake is that you do not write the correct expression for the net force on the pendulum bob. Since the tension balances one of the gravitational components, the correct net force is:
$$\vec F=-mg\sin\alpha\;\hat\theta.$$
WHy is there a minus sign? The minus sign comes from the fact that I am using the usual right-handed polar coordinates, i.e. $\hat r\times\hat \theta=\hat \phi$, where $\hat\phi$ is out of the page. So $\hat\theta$ is actually opposite the direction you have written it in your diagram. However, you don't have to use right-handed coordinates, however, your specification of $\vec F$ must change accordingly. At any rate if you work in either coordinates *correctly* then there will be a minus sign.
$$mg(-\sin\alpha\hat\theta)=(2\dot r\dot\alpha +r\ddot\alpha)\hat\theta.$$
So you get a set of coupled DEs, one for the radial, and one for the angular components:
$$-mg\sin(\alpha(t))=2\dot r\dot\alpha(t)+r\ddot\alpha.$$
Since $r$ is constant, these simplify to:
$$-mg\sin(\alpha(t)=r\ddot\alpha(t).$$
Solving this should definitely give you something besides the erroneous exponentials.

Comment: The rope remains the same length so $\dot r = \ddot r = 0$. You are saying I have to solve the set of equations, but if I change the axis as i said, I can solve only one and get the same answer?

Comment: @Dor Yes, the case of constant $r$ simplifies the equations.

Comment: @Dor Fixed the problem, take another look. You were incorrectly specifying the net force while working in left-handed coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. No one ever taught me that I must have $\hat r\times\hat \theta=\hat \phi$ in right handed coordinate

Comment: @Dor Yes, coordinates system have *orientation*, but the most important thing is that no matter what coordinates you use, the physics will be the same.  If you find that  different coordinates are giving you different physics then there is a mistake somewhere.